# extern an array of strings in C

Tags: c, gcc

The Names array of char* is located in file1.cpp

```
char* Names[] = {

    "name1",
    "name2",
    ...
    "nameN"
};
```

How do I declare it as "extern" in file2.cpp in order to get the values?

Comment: Why do you name your C files .cpp?

Comment: @nmichaels cpp = c preprocessor ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the array of char pointers in file2 as:

```
extern char*Names[];
```

A demo in C:

```
$ cat file1.c
char* Names[] = {"name1","name2","nameN" };

$ cat file2.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern char*Names[];

int  main() {
    printf("%s\n",Names[0]);
}
$ gcc file1.c file2.c && ./a.out
name1
```

Comment: however I actually like to read my code in english, i.e. with proper spacing between words, so I prefer a space after the * in the declaration. So extern char* Names[];
OTherwiseYourcode*looks*like*this;

Answer (score 2):

```
extern char *Names[];
```

This should probably go in file1.h.

Comment: What would happen if I try to get the array size using sizeof? Will it decay to a pointer and return sizeof(int)?

Comment: @Spidey: You'll get an error saying that you can't apply `sizeof` to incomplete types. If you `extern char *Names[3];` then you'll get the same thing you would have gotten if it had been in the same compilation unit: 3 * `sizeof(char *)`.

Answer (score 1):

You declare things as `extern` in the header:

```
// file1.h
extern char* Names[];

// file1.cpp
#include "file1.h"
char* Names[] = { ... };

// file2.cpp
#include "file1.h"
// You can use Names here.
```

There's nothing stopping you declaring it as `extern` in the .cpp file, but it is not common practice and will confuse people reading your code. It would also mean that file2.cpp would have to include file1.*cpp* or re-declare the array, which quickly becomes unmanageable.